# Font overflow on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts, safari

I have an issue with the font-family `Interstate WGL Bd` on iOS Devices with the Safari Browser only.
Using another font-family like `Interstate Bd` works like a charm.
Unfortunately, we can't use `Interstate Bd` because certain characters (like `č`) are rendered incorrectly.

I wish I could give you access to the current state, but unfortunately the project is not yet open to the public.
Also, I can not add a fiddle, because the font is licensed.

Let's get to the problem:
As you can see in the screenshot (made with an iPad Air 1 in the Safari), the text flows beyond the button.

[image: Screenshot]

And thats even though the button has no fixed width and is `display: inline-block;`.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

```css
.button {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-family: "Interstate WGL Bd", sans-serif;
  background: #008bd7;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button:before {
  content: "+";
  font-family: "icon";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a class="button" href="#">
    <span>SOME BUTTON TEXT THAT IS OVERFLOWING THE BUTTON</span>
  </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was caused by an error in the font.**

Our service provider (who supplies the fonts) has fixed the problem.

I cannot say how they did it exactly, because "https://www.typenetwork.com/" gives us no information.